# Write a Collection of paragraphs into a new document

Tags: vba, ms-office, ms-word

I need to write a function *SaveFileWithParagraphs*, that takes a path, filename and a Collection of paragraphs (which were extracted from a different word document) and simply writes the paragraphes into the new document with the same style etc.

What I have so far:

```
Sub SaveFileWithParagraphs(path As String, name As String, paras As Collection)
  Dim wrdApp As Word.Application
  Dim wrdDoc As Word.Document
  Dim i As Integer
  Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
  wrdApp.Visible = True
  Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Add

  With wrdDoc
    For Each p In paras            
        .Content.InsertAfter p.Range.Text
     Next
    .SaveAs (path + "\" + name)
    .Close ' close the document
  End With
wrdApp.Quit ' close the Word application
End Sub
```

The problem with this is that I loose the Styling of the paragraphs, since it only copies the plain text. Any ideas on how to solve this problem?

**Edit**

Thanks to Cominterns answer I got this:

```
' ...
With wrdDoc
   For Each p In paras
           p.Range.Copy
           Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdStory
           .Content.Paste
   Next
End With
' ...
```

Which copies my paragraphs keeping all the styling. Only one small problem remains: Whenever a new paragraph is copied, it overwrites the previously copied one, so that in the end only the last paragraph remains in the document. This seems like an easy to solve problem, but I cant get it to work. Any further help is much appreciated. :)

Comment: have you looked into CopyFormat? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840230.aspx

Comment: How do you extract the paragraphs from the other document?

Comment: @Sorceri I am not sure how exactly I can use CopyFormat in my code, but I will try that thank you!

Comment: @Comintern I am basically iterating through all the paragraphs in the first document with a for each Loop and if I need to extract one I just copy it to a collection.

Comment: With `.Copy`, or do you store the actual `Paragraph` object?

Comment: @Comintern I am storing the Paragraph object in a Collection, yes. There is nothing selected or something like that. 
Maybe I am doing something stupid after all, I am pretty new to VBA programming for Word/Excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`p.Range.Text` is exactly that - the text. If you want to keep the formatting, you can copy the range and then paste it:

```
Dim target As Range
With wrdDoc
    For Each p In paras
        p.Range.Copy
        Set target = .Range
        target.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        target.PasteAndFormat wdFormatOriginalFormatting
    Next
    .SaveAs (path + "\" + name)
    .Close ' close the document
End With
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunatly this gives me an "Expected Function or variable"-Error at .Collapse.

Comment: @FlorianBaierl - That'll teach me to whip something up without testing it... See the edit.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you very much!